# How to display a 3D object in browser?

Tags: silverlight

We have a project that requires to display a 3D object on the browser and get user's feedback from the mouse click. For example, if the user clicks one part of the 3D object, we should display an annotation text, etc.

What kind of technique we have to use?

ASP.NET? SilverLight?

Thank you

> // updated based on one of comments

The 3D object is not an image of 3D object. It is a real 3D object constructed from 3D meshes. The application needs to provide all common operations for the user so that the user can pan, rotate, zoom, annotate the 3D object.

Thank you

Comment: The "etc." is an important part of your question.  What you've described doesn't really require any 3D engine.  Just use a picture.  Do they need to rotate the image, zoom in, see the back, see the inside, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The perspective projection features of Silverlight aren't really suitable for complex meshes, so your best bet is probably a 3D engine such as [Balder](http://balder.codeplex.com/). I haven't used it but the sample browser seems fairly comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

SilverMotion is the most advanced software 3d engine for Silverlight I know of. Check out the demo: http://postvision.net/SilverMotion/DemoTech.aspx. Kit3d is another engine, but I don't know if it is supported or not. Balder was already mentioned.